# How to change input fields while overriding a django save() method

Tags: python, django

Suppose I had this following code:

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
     ...
     ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # pre-save edits can go here...
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I create and save a model, MyModel(blah, blah, blah), there is a possibility that
one of the input fields is "None". In the overridden save method, the goal is to check for if a field is none, and if one is, change it to some other default value.

Are the input fields in args or kwargs? And is overriding save() even the proper way to do this?

I was thinking something like this:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in args and args['username'] is None:
              args['username'] = some_default_value
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So where are the input params? args* or **kwargs, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's better a `pre_save` signal to see if a input value is `None`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def mymodel_save_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if instance.field1 is None or instance.field1 == "":
         instance.field1 = default_value
```

If you prefer override `save` method you can access to the `model` `fields` with `self`

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.username is None:
              self.username = some_default_value
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: im getting a compile error, are u sure sender=MyModel isn't supposed to be sender='MyModel'?

Comment: Thanks, if anyone still can help, still a bit curious. Where can the instance fields be accessed when over-riding a save() method? Is it in args or kwargs?